# How to click on Web Table column's Web Button in following case?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

[image: Web Table]

I have one web table, in this I want to delete particular record by clicking on record's delete button.

I got the value of row but I am not able to perform click on web button of particular row and also there is 2 buttons in one column.

How to click on delete icon of particular row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a reference to the item within the specific row and then click on it - something like this:

```
Set oLink = Browser("myBrowser").Page("myPage").WebTable("myTable").ChildItem(iRow,8,"Link",0)
oLink.Click
```

You will potentially need to amend the `"Link"` and the number `8` in your own code.  `iRow` represents the row you are trying to interact with.

Essentially what this code does is set an object reference to the first item of type `"Link"`, in column `8` of the table, then uses a `Click` event to select it.  If your delete icon is a `WebButton`, then replace `"Link"` with `"WebButton"` for example.  The final `0` in the command tells `UFT` to select the first element matching the object type - you might need `1` if your two icons are in the same column of the table.

Let me know if that helped.